# How to query only groups that don't have an 'owner'?

Tags: sql

[image: example]

I want to query only group_id that don't have a role = 'owner' to delete it then I try to do like this

```
select group_id from group_members where role != 'owner'
```

but when I get a group_id, it still has the role 'owner'

ex result:> `group_id = g001(but g001 has role 'owner') and g002`

it should query `just group_id = g002`

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT G.GROUP_ID 
FROM GROUP_MEMBER AS G
WHERE NOT EXISTS
 (
   SELECT 1 FROM GROUP_MEMBER AS X WHERE G.GROUP_ID=X.GROUP_ID AND X.ROLE='OWNER'
 )
```

Comment: Thanks!, Im already solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Use where not in.

```
 select group_id from group_members where group_id NOT IN (select DISTINCT(group_id) from group_members where role == 'owner');
```